# IIS Won't authenticate domain user: 401.2

Tags: domain, iis, authentication

I'm having a lot of trouble with configuring authentication for IIS correctly.  I have a SharePoint site running under IIS 6.0, and the IIS web site is configured for Integrated Windows Authentication.  The web server is on a domain called `STAGING`, and most of my users are an another domain, called `CORP`.  The `CORP` users have `STAGING` domain accounts, and are able to log into the SharePoint site across the domains (e.g., the users are logged into their `CORP` workstations and are able to log in to the site).  However, `STAGING` domain users are unable to log in from within the `STAGING` domain.  My understanding was that `STAGING` domain users should be able to access the site without being prompted for credentials, but this isn't the case.  Even so, once the credentials are entered, the result is always a 401.

I looked at the HTTP session in Fiddler, and it appears that the server simple isn't accepting the negotiated credentials sent by the client browser.  Here's an abbreviated record:

```
HTTP GET  server /sites/mysite with headers: { }
    --> 401.2, with headers: { WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM }
HTTP GET  server /sites/mysite with headers: { Authorization: Negotiate <digest1> }
    --> 401.1, with headers: { WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <digest2> }
HTTP GET  server /sites/mysite with headers: { Authorization: Negotiate <digest3> }
    --> 401.1, with headers: { WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <digest4> }
```

The GET/401.1 cycle repeats 3 times before the browser finally gives up.

I would expect that if I had everything configured correctly, the in-domain client would just pass the credentials and life would be good, but that's not what's happening, and life isn't good :-(

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This should most likely be moved to serverfault.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I kinda had a feeling this wasn't the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a Kerberos/SPN issue.  Simple fix is to disable Kerberos in favor of NTLM.  You do this in Sharepoint's Central Administration site.

You could also add the SPN's for your site to the SharePoint Service Account.

See

- [Setting Kerberos and NTLM - KB 832769](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832769)
- [Configuring Kerberos for SharePoint 2007: Part 1 - Base Configuration for SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/martinkearn/archive/2007/04/23/configuring-kerberos-for-sharepoint-2007-part-1-base-configuration-for-sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be the issue.  When I forced NTLM-only authentication, it all worked just fine.  Turns out I had done exactly nothing to get Kerberos working, so naturally it didn't work :-)